# Does INSERT INTO ... SELECT require lock (FOR UPDATE)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using `PostgreSQL`. Here is a simplified query that I have:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT values
FROM TableB 
JOIN tables
LEFT JOIN TableA
WHERE conditions
AND TableA.X IS NULL
```

It adds new record to `TableA` but only if it does not exist.
When I run this query sequentially I get only one new record created.
But what if multiple threads will run it in parallel? Is it possible that more that one record in TableA will be created?

Do I need to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to lock records in `TableB`?

Comment: Yes, this might lead to duplicate rows in the target table if concurrent transactions run the same query. The only efficient and safe way to prevent duplicates is to create a unique index (or constraint), then use `insert ... on conflict` to deal with that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What about `select ... for update skip locked`? When applied to one of the source tables it makes locked records temporary invisible? Right?

Comment: The select part will skip rows that are _currently_ being locked, correct. That still doesn't prevent duplicates in the _target_ table. The only efficient way to to that is a unique index/constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two of these statements are running concurrently, none of the `SELECT`s can see the `INSERT` of the other (because neither transaction is committed yet). So they may insert the same row twice.

The best way to avoid that is to use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` with a unique or primary key constraint.

Comment: @Luuk No, that is wrong. PostgreSQL will automatically upgrade `READ UNCOMMITTED` to `READ COMMITTED` (which is condoned by the SQL standard). You are linking to the MySQL documentation.